# Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag link. asp.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my asp.net MVC project, I created a view as a report.

So then from the controller other than passing the view, I wanted to generate a pdf from the view and send the front end as a PDF file.

For this I used iTextSharp nuget package.

The issue is when I run I got an error from the view as

> iTextSharp.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested
> tag head found, expected closing tag link.

I checked my HTML code and it looks fine.

This is my controller code

```
public ActionResult PrintTransferDetails(int ID)
        {
            try
            {
                var transferNote = db.LocationTransferMain.Find(ID);
                var companyDetails = db.Company.Find(transferNote.Company_ID);
                var viewModel = new TransferViewModel
                {
                    CompanyLogo = companyDetails.CompanyLogo,
                    CompanyAddress = companyDetails.CompanyAddress + ". " + companyDetails.CompanyCity,
                    CompanyContactNo = companyDetails.CompanyMainPhoneNumber + ". " + companyDetails.CompanySecondaryPhoneNumber + ". " +companyDetails.CompanyFaxNumber,
                    CompanyName = companyDetails.CompanyName,
                    TransferNote = transferNote.TransferNote_ReffCode,
                    TransferDate = transferNote.Transfer_Date,
                    TransferredBy = db.Employee.Find(transferNote.CreatedByEmpId).FullName,
                    TransferItems = (from m in db.LocationTransferSub
                                     join l in db.CompanyLocations on m.New_Location_ID equals l.ID
                                     where m.Transfer_Main_ID == ID
                                     select new TransferItemViewModel
                                     {
                                         ItemName = m.Items.ItemName_Number,
                                         CurrentLocation = m.CurrentCompanyLocation.LocationName,
                                         CurrentLocationQty = m.Current_Location_Qty,
                                         NewLocation = l.LocationName,
                                         NewLocationQty = m.New_Location_Qty
                                     }).ToList(),

                };
                var pdfHtml = RenderViewToString("_PrintTransferDetails", viewModel);
                

                var pdfBytes = ConvertHtmlToPdf(pdfHtml);

                return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf", "TransferNote.pdf");

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            
        }

        private byte[] ConvertHtmlToPdf(string html)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                var writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

                document.Open();
                using (var htmlStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
                {
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                }
                document.Close();

                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
       
        private string RenderViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {

                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, null);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

This is the HTML View

```
@model EvoPOS.WebUI.Models.TransferViewModel


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Print Transfer Details</title>
        <style>
        /* Outer style adjustments */
        .print-content {
            width: 331mm;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .logo img {
            max-width: 150px;
            height: auto;
        }

        .company-details {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .transfer-details h2 {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .transfer-table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

            .transfer-table th,
            .transfer-table td {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                padding: 8px;
            }

        .signatures p {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        /* Media print styles */
        /* @@ media print {
            body {
                background: white;
            }

            .transfer-table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 100%;
            }

            footer {
                display: none !important;
            }
        }*/
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="card mb-4">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="print-content">
                                <div class="header">
                                    <div class="logo">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/@Model.CompanyLogo" height="100" width="auto" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="company-details">
                                        <h3>@Model.CompanyName</h3>
                                        <p>Address: @Model.CompanyAddress</p>
                                        <p>Contact: @Model.CompanyContactNo</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="transfer-details">
                                    <h2>Transfer Note: @Model.TransferNote</h2>
                                    <p>Transfer Date: @Model.TransferDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</p>
                                    <p>Transferred By: @Model.TransferredBy</p>
                                </div>
                                <table class="transfer-table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width="25%">Item Name</th>
                                            <th width="20%">Current Location</th>
                                            <th width="10%">Current Location Qty</th>
                                            <th width="20%">New Allocated Location</th>
                                            <th width="10%">Allocated Qty</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    @foreach (var item in Model.TransferItems)
                                    {
                                        
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>@item.ItemName</td>
                                            <td>@item.CurrentLocation</td>
                                            <td>@item.CurrentLocationQty</td>
                                            <td>@item.NewLocation</td>
                                            <td>@item.NewLocationQty</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <div class="signatures">
                                    <p>Transferred Employee Signature: ________________________</p>
                                    <p>Manager's Signature: ________________________</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mt-4">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="printButton">Print</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="saveButton">Save as PDF</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="transferDetailsContainer">
                <!-- Content from the partial view will be inserted here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Appriciate help If I can get. :)

Comment: what is inside pdfHtml variable?